# Entity Framework Navigation Properties on Views

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am a little confused on how navigation properties work on MVC.

Let's take a look at this code:

```
var messages = db.messages // .Include("user_reciever").Include("user_sender")
    .Where(M => M.receiver_id == _User.id && M.delete_code != 1)
    .OrderByDescending(M => M.timestamp);

return View(messages.ToList());
```

I excluded the Include field so "user_reciever" and "user_sender" are not included.

However, in my View, I have this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var tr_style = item.message_read == false ? "font-weight:bold" : "";
    <tr style="@tr_style">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="MessageIds" id="MessageIds" value="@item.id"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.message_read)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.user_sender.username, "Overview", "User", new { username = item.user_sender.username }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.subject, "Details", new { id = item.id })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timestamp)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Notice how I am using this code: username = item.user_sender.username, however, I did NOT include the "user_sender" on the Db Call.

Even without it, this code still works.

So my questions are:

1. Navigation Properties work by calling the DB using a join statement, is that correct?
2. When you use Navigation Properties like item.user_sender.username, is that a separate call to the DB? That would mean that foreach is calling the DB for each item, right?
3. In that code above, am I calling the DB for every foreach item? If I added the .Include("user_reciever").Include("user_sender"), would that mean I won't be calling the Db for every foreach item? (I am guessing no because all the items are already pre-loaded with one db join statement)
4. Is this an effective way to run this code? I wan't to display the user messages that contains the Username from another table. I user Sender_id, Reciever_id to find out who sent it and who recieved it.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Navigation Properties work by calling the DB using a join statement,
>       is that correct?

Depends on how you load the navigational property. If you use `Include` method to load them then it will use `join`s. If these properites are lazy loaded it will not require a `join`

> When you use Navigation Properties like item.user_sender.username,
>       is that a separate call to the DB? That would mean that foreach is
>       calling the DB for each item, right?

Yes. If you do not use the `include` method

> In that code above, am I calling the DB for every foreach item? If I
>       added the .Include("user_reciever").Include("user_sender"), would
>       that mean I won't be calling the Db for every foreach item? (I am
>       guessing no because all the items are already pre-loaded with one db
>       join statement)

Yes.

> Is this an effective way to run this code? I wan't to display the
>       user messages that contains the Username from another table. I user
>       Sender_id, Reciever_id to find out who sent it and who recieved it.

Using the `Include` method is more effective here. You can project the query results to load  only the required fields. This will be faster than using the `Include` methods.

```
var messages = db.messages
                         .Where(M => M.receiver_id == _User.id && M.delete_code != 1)
                         .OrderByDescending(M => M.timestamp)
                         .Select(m => new MessageModel { Id = m.id, Sender = m.user_sender.username, /* etc */ }).
```